# How to create a visual basic.net database application using ms access 2007

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I trying to create an application using vb 2010.This application handles booking of airline customers. i am using ms access 2007 where i have created a table that stores customer information and another that stores and updates seats available in different flying classes. Am trying to develop an interactive application in visual basic 2010 where customers can book. i want to add this data to the database in real time and communicate to customers the seats available,prices and so forth. In otherwards the application communicates with database and updates accordingly. Firstly how do i connect to my database? I tried ADO.net but seems better equiped to work with sql server which i have no idea how to use. Is there a tool that can make my interaction with the access seamless? or are there any useful resources which can guide me with working access 2007 and vb.net?

Comment: I would recommend that you used SQL Server, MySQL or some other database.  Access is not very good when there are multiple users accessing it over a network.  You can design your database in access and then upsize it afterwards but you would really be better off learning SQL.  Both SQL Server Express and MySQL are free!  There are also many other databases out there some of which are NoSQL (e.g MongoDB)

Comment: You can connect to an MS Access database from ADO.NET by creating an ODBC data source for it but I agree with David: building a multi-user application on Access is a bad idea.

Comment: Multi-user apps with a Jet/ACE back end are JUST FINE. It just depends on HOW MANY simultaneous users you have. If you have 5 or 10, things will be fine. If you've got 25 or more, upsizing might be in order, but it depends on what they are doing -- 25 read-only users is not going to be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this step-by-step by Microsoft on how to use vb.net to connect to a access database. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821765.

I agree with David and Ken, why not use SQL Server Express or MySQL, they are free and easy to use, and much better to work with multi-users.

Comment: Can you show me any resources that specifically deal with vb.net and mysql?

Comment: Sure, here we go: [VB.net MySQL](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-3) you will need the MySQL Connector/NET you can download it here [http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).